# Jquery Plugin is not working in IE browser but its working fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am implementing the multipicker functionality using jquery multipicker plugin, this is working fine in chrome and firefox but not working in IE browser,
Here is my plunker link: `enter code here`

https://plnkr.co/edit/edMu2nN3ZNJJTnliE9OM?p=preview

Error In IE: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign

Comment: Post it as a bug in plugin repo. Can switch to using `$.extend` or include this polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Comment: Where I have to place this playfill in code..

Comment: Thanku its working fine...

Comment: Hi, I just saw your question and replaced assign with $.extend as @charlietfl suggested, write here https://github.com/styopdev/multiPicker/issues if you will have another question or issue related to plugin, Thanks Stepan